# WPF share string between 2 viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm a newbie in this WPF world, I have the following situation:

I am developing a multimedia-related application using VLC and the Caliburn.Micro, I have encountered a problem where I need the variable `TotalTime` from the `MainViewModel` to be shared with the `TextBox` on the `SettingsViewModel`.

This variable happens to change every second, so it has to be notified every second.

```
MainViewModel -> string TotalTime

SettingsViewModel -> TextBox Time
```

I have tried to do it with events, but I haven't succeeded.

Comment: Could you post the code for the two view models? Without seeing the code and their relationship this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you nest the SettingsViewModel in the MainViewModel as a property (say Settings), you can bind an UI element to it like this:

```
Text = "{Binding Path=Settings.TotalTime}"
```

if the View's DataContext is set to an instance of the MainViewModel

Answer (score -1):

In general, the solution to this problem is a singleton messenger that both view-models have injected into them on creation (usually from an IoC container). In your scenario, `SettingsViewModel` would subscribe to messages of a particular type, say `TotalTimeChangedMessage`, and `MainViewModel` would send messages of that type whenever `TotalTime` changed. The message simply contains the current value of `TotalTime`, e.g.:

```
public sealed class TotalTimeChangedMessage
{
    public string totalTime;

    public TotalTimeChangedMessage(string totalTime)
    {
        this.totalTime = totalTime;
    }

    public string TotalTime
    {
        get { return this.totalTime; }
    }
}
```

Caliburn.Micro contains an [event aggregator](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator) that you can use to pass messages in this fashion between view-models. Your `MainViewModel` would send the message like this:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    public string TotalTime
    {
        set
        {
            this.totalTime = value;
            _eventAggregator.Publish(new TotalTimeChangedMessage(this.totalTime));
        }
    }
}
```

..and your `SettingsViewModel` would handle it like this:

```
public class SettingsViewModel: IHandle<TotalTimeChangedMessage>
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

    public SettingsViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void Handle(TotalTimeChangedMessage message)
    {
        // Use message.TotalTime as necessary
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you are using Event Aggregation to notify a viewmodel that a property has changed? Why not simply listen to "PropertyChanged" event on the parent view model? This is basically taking a cannon to a water gun fight.

Comment: Nowhere in the question does it state that the `SettingsViewModel` is a child of `MainViewModel`. And it shouldn't be changed to be a child for the purpose of getting a single `string` value - that adds a dependency on `MainViewModel` into `SettingsViewModel`, and introduces tight coupling between them.

Comment: Exactly, SettingsViewModel is not a child of MainViewModel